# Updating WSDL file ,generates new reference file

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

on updating web reference , visual studio generates another class instead of over-writing same class in another reference1.cs file

Comment: This is normal. It will delete the old reference files and add the new reference files to source control (assuming you are linked to source control) - unless you mean that it's creating new references *in addition* to the existing ones.

Comment: i also have same issue. when i update service reference , it creates another reference.cs file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to modify the .wsdl file.

1. You need to remove old version class reference and keep new version as default one
2. remove all .xsd files in Service Reference and edit '*.svcmap' file remove all references from `<MetaData>` tag.
3. Delete all files under *.svcmap tree

Comment: I can't make sense of this answer. Could you elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this by simply removing the entire Web Reference from the project and re-added it back. After that everything back to normal, now when updating the Web Reference no more additional Reference.cs files were generated.

Hope this will help.